# HTML: Keep an element as high as possible within it's own element without going off-screen

Tags: html, css

Imagine a long list of blog posts, each with a profile picture to its left. I would like to know an effective (cross-browser) way to have the profile picture stay to the left of the upper most part of its blog post currently on screen:

The page would open like this:

```
--------------------Top of window-----------------
   ---  --------------------------------------
   |A|  | A's post                           |
   ---  |                                    |
        |                                    |
        | Line 4                             |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        --------------------------------------

   ---  --------------------------------------
   |B|  | B's post                           |
   ---  |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        --------------------------------------
```

But when the page is scrolled down it would look like this:

```
--------------------Top of window-----------------
   ---  | Line 4                             |
   |A|  |                                    |
   ---  |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        --------------------------------------

   ---  --------------------------------------
   |B|  | B's post                           |
   ---  |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        --------------------------------------
```

And finally like this (notice as the bottom of A's profile picture aligns with the bottom of the blog post both of them move off the top of the screen):

```
--------------------Top of window-----------------
   |A|  |                                    |
   ---  --------------------------------------

   ---  --------------------------------------
   |B|  | B's post                           |
   ---  |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        |                                    |
        --------------------------------------
```

I hope my explanation is clear!

Ideally I would be able to implement this entirely in CSS (I highly doubt this is possible while supporting IE7!) But efficient ways to achieve this using jQuery would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to check with javascript when this item go's off screen and than set its css position to fixed, there is no css only way to do this.